# turn dictionary into list, sort and then return table

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Ok so I have to take a dictionary as a parameter and sort the keys and values associated with keys. I know I cannot sort dictionaries so I thought about putting them into a list and then sorting them. but what I need to print out is a table, which is a list or a string with the proper format that it will print each key in a new line. This is what the code should be doing:

```
>>> dict1 = {'Animals': ['Anteaters', 'Bulls', 'Mountain Lion', 'Camel', 
'Polar Bear', 'Kangaroo'], 'Amphibians': ['Frog', 'Toads', 'Salamanders'], 
'Insects': ['Butterflies', 'Ants', 'Beetles', 'Bee', 'Centipede']}


>>> animals(dict1)
￼Amphibians
￼ Frog
￼ Salamanders
￼ Toads
￼Animals
￼ Anteaters
￼ Bulls
￼ Camel
￼ Kangaroo
￼ Mountain Lion
￼ Polar Bear
￼Insects
￼ Ants
￼ Bee
￼ Beetles
￼ Butterflies
￼ Centipede
```

So how can I format the table to look like this when printing the final list or string. I don't know what is the best way to do this. This is the code I have so far but clearly it is wrong:

```
def animals(aDict):
    animalslist=[]
    for keys,values in aDict.items():
        animalslist.append(keys)
        animalslist. append.(values)
        keys.sort()
        values.sort()
    myTable=' '
    for each in animalslist:
        value=aDict[each]
        myTable = myTable + '\n' +each + ' ' +str(aDict[each])
    return myTable
```

Please help me, because I do not know how to turn this dictionary into something I can sort and the print in out with the right format to make it look like a table. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track. You can first use `sorted` on the top level keys to print in order of kingdom (I think? I forgot my taxonomy terms). Then within each of those, sort the inner list and print with a padded space.

```
def animals(d):
    for key in sorted(d.keys()):
        print(key)
        for animal in sorted(d[key]):
            print(' ' + animal)

>>> animals(dict1)
Amphibians
 Frog
 Salamanders
 Toads
Animals
 Anteaters
 Bulls
 Camel
 Kangaroo
 Mountain Lion
 Polar Bear
Insects
 Ants
 Bee
 Beetles
 Butterflies
 Centipede
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = aDict.keys()
values = aDict.values()
```

That way you have 2 sortable lists.

To sort them, as you post:

```
list.sort()
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use OrderedDict:

```
>>> # regular unsorted dictionary
>>> d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}
>>> # dictionary sorted by key
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
```

After that, you can go over the OrderedDict and print your table.